# Pyspark - ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkContext' from 'pyspark'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing the below error when I am developing data pipeline using python and pyspark.

> PS
>   C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data>
>   python test.py Traceback (most recent call last):      File "test.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from pyspark.conf import SparkConf   File "C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark__init__.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       from pyspark.context import SparkContext   File "C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       from pyspark.profiler import ProfilerCollector, BasicProfiler   File
>   "C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\profiler.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       import cProfile   File "C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\cProfile.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       import profile as _pyprofile   File "C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data\profile.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from awsglue.context import GlueContext   File "C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data\awsglue__init__.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from .dynamicframe import DynamicFrame   File "C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data\awsglue\dynamicframe.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame   File "C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql__init__.py",
>   line 45, in 
>       from pyspark.sql.types import Row   File "C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py",
>   line 36, in 
>       from pyspark import SparkContext ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkContext' from 'pyspark'
>   (C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark__init__.py)

The code is a really simple one only to try it:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

print("hello world")
```

Java, spark, python and pyspark are properly installed as below:

```
> PS
> C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data>
> java -version java version "1.8.0_241" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 1.8.0_241-b07) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 25.241-b07, mixed mode) PS C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data>


> PS
> C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data> python --version 
> Python 3.7.6


> PS
> C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data>
> spark-shell --version Welcome to
>       ____              __
>      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
>     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
>       /_/
> 
> Using Scala version 2.11.12, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM,
> 1.8.0_231 Branch heads/v2.4.3 Compiled by user vaviliv on 2019-09-17T17:31:05Z Revision c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a
> Url https://github.com/apache/spark Type --help for more information.


> PS
> C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\projects\code\etl-gd\src\jobs\greater-data>
> pyspark --version
>     Welcome to
>           ____              __
>          / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
>         _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
>        /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
>           /_/
>     
>     Using Scala version 2.11.12, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_231
>     Branch heads/v2.4.3
>     Compiled by user vaviliv on 2019-09-17T17:31:05Z
>     Revision c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a
>     Url https://github.com/apache/spark
>     Type --help for more information.
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I created a separated virtual environment because I had some version of python and spark in my computer.

Comment: So some versions of python and spark are incompatible? You solved the problem by creating a new virtual env and then? Just reinstall the latest versions of each?

Comment: I think what he said and I tested it out for my similar issue is that your spark and pyspark version should be compatible (same version). So if you dont want to change your current env, just create a new one with compatible version for both and it will work.